# Spring Security getPrincipal() method returns anonymousUser

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

in my spring web application I want to get an authenticated user in my controller:

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

But the principal's value is "anonymousUser" although I have loged in.
How can I get an authenticated user?
My configurations in spring-security.xml:

```
<http auto-config="true" request-matcher="regex">
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>
```

Comment: Which URL did you request when you got "anonymousUser"?

Comment: http://localhost/test.html

Comment: How should SS come into play here? You configured it to only intercept `/welcome*`...

Comment: but I want text.html page available for both authenticated and not authenticated users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure I understand but try this

```
<http auto-config="true" request-matcher="regex">
  <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED,IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
```

Comment: thank you very much for the idea! it works for me, but with access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ANONYMOUSLY" instead of access="IS_AUTHENTICATED,IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"

Comment: @Ukrainianguy, glad it works, consider accepting the answer. `ROLE_ANONYMOUSLY` is not correct, it's `ROLE_ANONYMOUS`. Whether you need to check for `ROLE_` or `IS_` depends on the context. Technically there are only minor differences between the two.